# Why do I keep getting Invalid project name when creating a web-worker?

Tags: angular, web-worker

I am updating an angular app to use web workers. I am trying to follow this guide:  [guide](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker)

But when I try this:

```
ng generate web-worker app
```

I get the following error

```
Invalid project name (project-ui)
```

Anyone knows why?

here are the versions of everything I am using:

```
Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.1001.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.1000.4
@angular-devkit/core               10.0.8
@angular-devkit/schematics         10.0.8
@angular/cdk                       10.2.7
@angular/cli                       10.1.0
@angular/localize                  11.0.9
@ngtools/webpack                   10.0.4
@schematics/angular                10.0.8
@schematics/update                 0.1001.0
ng-packagr                         10.1.0
rxjs                               6.6.3
typescript                         4.0.3
webpack                            4.46.0
```

Comment: Are you executing the command inside your project directory/path?

Comment: I actually was not. I am in now and Get Cannot find base TypeScript configuration file 'tsconfig.base.json'.

Comment: what angular version are you using?

Comment: I am using 10.1.0